# How can I fix KeyError: (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

So I am trying to create a bot that bans a user that is not whitelisted when they ban a member, here is the code.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_ban(guild, user):
      with open('whitelisted.json') as f:
        whitelisted = json.load(f)
      async for i in guild.audit_logs(limit=1, action=discord.AuditLogAction.ban):
      
          if str(i.user.id) in whitelisted[str(guild.id)]:
            return
    
          await guild.ban(i.user, reason="Anti-Nuke: Banning Members")
          await guild.kick(i.user, reason="Anti-Nuke: Banning Members")
          return
```

Here is the error  `if str(i.user.id) in whitelisted[str(guild.id)]: KeyError: '869040077815296091'`

Answer (score 2):

A `KeyError` is an error due to the dict that does not contains the key for the object selected, and I quote from the [Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError):

> Python raises a `KeyError` whenever a `dict()` object is requested (using the format `a = adict[key])` and the key is not in the dictionary.

Said so, you can simply overcome this error by ensuring the key exists, like:

```py
if str(guild.id) in whitelisted.keys():
    if str(i.user.id) in whitelisted[str(guild.id)]:
        return
```